# Primeng menubar ng-template start and end or not showing even after doing the same way in example

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to use the sample provide in [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar), but somehow I am not able to get it work with ng-templates. [modified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-demo-zlupid-fork?file=src/app/app.component.html) the stackblitz provided in example and tried but no luck. please help me to figure out what am I missing
Below is my header code

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
  <ng-template pTemplate="start">
    <img src="assets/showcase/images/primeng.svg" height="40" class="p-mr-2">
  </ng-template>
 <ng-template pTemplate="end">
    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Search">
 </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

[image: output]My local packages are

```
 {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.3",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.3",
"ngx-electron": "^2.2.0",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^11.4.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
}
```

[image: Template shown in primeng docs]

Comment: The stackblitz doesn't look like what you're showing here.

Comment: @eko image is from local stackblitz is for reference code

Answer (score 16):

Updating the answer based on comment:
One module import was missing in `app.module.ts`'s `imports` array which is required for the desired output. So, please import `TabViewModule` and add it into the import array.

Adding the imports array:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MenubarModule,
    InputTextModule,
    TabViewModule,
  ]
```

and HTML template:

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
  <ng-template pTemplate="start">
    <img src="assets/primeng.svg" height="40" class="p-mr-2">
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="end">
    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Search">
  </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

Please refer to updated demo link in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-demo-zlupid-fork-f3ypey?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Demo image for reference:
[image]

Comment: updated snippet give in primeng docs please check

Comment: Okay but I still don't understand what output are you expecting from the given snippet?

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer. Please go through the demo link as well and let me know if you face any issue regarding it. Also do upvote and accept the answer if it resolves your query.

Comment: This started happening with angular 12  as well, TabViewModule  import fixed the issue for me , thanks.

Answer (score 5):

While importing TabViewModule (in Ali's answer) makes the problem go away, I think it's enough to import `SharedModule` from primeng/api (TabViewModule imports SharedModule which has the necessary `PrimeTemplate` class defined).

Comment: yes, i confirm and this should be the accepted answer !